# Akka: Transforming the Input of a Sink with a Materialized Value

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a sink: `Sink[String, Mat]` and want to transform it into the sink: `Sink[Int, Mat]` by mapping each element: `num: Int => ("num" + num): String` and keeping the original materialized type and value.

If `Mat` was `Unit`, then it's easy:

```
def transformSink(sink: Sink[String, Unit]): Sink[Int, Unit] =
  Flow[Int].map("num" + _).to(sink)
```

But what about transforming a sink for any `Mat`?

```
def transformSink[Mat](sink: Sink[String, Mat]): Sink[Int, Mat] = ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `toMat` is what you are looking for.  See if this works for you:

```
def transformSink[Mat](sink: Sink[String, Mat]): Sink[Int, Mat] =
  Flow[Int].map("num" + _).toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks.